# How can I use non-integer without using float in LUA

Tags: lua, lua-table, logitech-gaming-software

In LUA for MoveMouse i can't use FLOAT. So i need to get around it. I don't know how to do this. So i need help.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    local multiplier = 2
         if smth == CODE then
                MoveMouseRelative(-1*multiplier, 0.1*multiplier)
                Sleep(10)
                MoveMouseRelative(-1*multiplier, 0.2*multiplier)
                Sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store fractional `value` in a variable and pass `math.floor(value)` to your functions.
Unspent fractional part will be accumulated for future using.

```
local x_frac, y_frac = 0

local function MoveMouseRelativeFractional(x, y)
   x_frac = x_frac + x
   y_frac = y_frac + y
   local x_int = math.floor(x_frac)
   local y_int = math.floor(y_frac)
   x_frac = x_frac - x_int
   y_frac = y_frac - y_int
   if x_int ~= 0 or y_int ~= 0 then
      MoveMouseRelative(x_int, y_int)
   end
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   local multiplier = 2
   if smth == CODE then
      MoveMouseRelativeFractional(-1*multiplier, 0.1*multiplier)
      Sleep(10)
      MoveMouseRelativeFractional(-1*multiplier, 0.2*multiplier)
      Sleep(10)
```